# Wordpress: how do you get jQuery scripts to work when jquery is enqueued?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using this little snippet of jQuery in my header.php file:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
 $('#menu-classes h3 a').removeAttr("href");
});
</script>
```

It works fine when I include jQuery like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But it doesn't work at all if I include jQuery the "correct" Wordpress way (enqueue), like this:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I guess if you just use this Wordpress tag, your jquery functions are unknown because you do not reference to the jquery library.

Comment: how do i reference to the jquery library?

Comment: I found this tutorial [http://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/](http://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/) probably you just have to follow this - it is not sufficient to use just the tag.

Comment: The [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) explains very clearly how to load scripts properly. Add them to your `functions.php` and then configure the enqueue action.

Comment: Thanks Cruxi - i figured out, I was adding my script BEFORE the <?php wp_head() ?> tag. For some weird reason, you have to add it AFTER it.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to stick to codex about scripts.

[wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

> Use the wp_enqueue_scripts action to call this function, or admin_enqueue_scripts to call it on the admin side, or use login_enqueue_scripts for login screens.

That would be.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_theme_scripts' );

function enqueue_theme_scripts() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
```

Comment: True, thanks. I usually would register it and enqueue it. However, at the moment I just wanted to quickly test a script in my own theme so dropped in the header within script tags, which you can also do fine, although it is preferable to do it the "correct" way of course to avoid conflicts etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because the correct way is to do it in the theme's `functions.php`, not in a template.

As @Zlatev points outs, it has to be encapsulated inside an action hook. Check the Codex for the *really* official way.

This Q&A may be helpful: [Including jQuery and jQuery files the correct way](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/45437/12615).

Comment: It won't create any problems doing it this way temporarily if you have no plugins etc. Which is my case - i.e. building a simple theme, no plugins, no other scripts, and just want to quickly drop in some jquery to test it out.

Comment: @user1444027 Your theme, your WP, your way :) As long as you know how to it really correct, np.

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to use it in no conflicts mode,

> jQuery(document).ready(function($) { .. stuff ... }

Answer (score -1):

Just in case anyone else out there gets stuck on this problem:

Make sure your script is included AFTER the `<?php wp_head(); ?>`.

Of course, this is the unofficial way to include a script in Wordpress and may create script conflicts if you are using plugins for example. The official way is to register the script in functions.php and then enqueue it.